# How can I calculate the surface area of a plane wing

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airfoil

I want to determine the surface area of an aircraft wing using calculus, specifically focusing on the cross-sectional area (thickness distribution) formula. Although I am unsure if there exists a specific formula for this purpose, I am interested in understanding how to calculate the curved surface area of an airplane wing without relying on aerodynamic equations. I have provided images, which may aid in visualizing the three-dimensional aspects. In the figures, the cross-sectional area is defined using airfoil equations, incorporating a thickness distribution equation. (I asked this question on Math Stack Exchange but didn't get an answer so I decided to ask it here.) [image: 3D plane wing]Second image

[image]It is noteworthy that the cross-sectional area of aircraft wings tends to increase as they approach the fuselage, with C1 and C2 representing the initial and final chord lengths. The variable L denotes the length of the aircraft wing.

General Thickness Distribution formula:
$$y_{t}=\pm5ct[0.2969\sqrt{α}-0.1260α-0.3516α^{2}+0.2843α^{3}-0.1015α^{4}]$$

Thickness Distribution formula for NACA 2412 (which I want to find): $$y_{t}=\pm0.60[0.2969\sqrt{α}-0.1260α-0.3516α^{2}+0.2843α^{3}-0.1015α^{4}]$$

Where c is the chord length, α = x/c and t is the maximum thickness expressed as a fraction of the chord length. In other words, 1/100 last two digits×chord length.

It is not necessary to use the given values, but you can if you want.

$$L = 30m$$
$$C1= 3m$$
$$C2= 1.5m$$